# telegram Bot Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am making a telegram chatbot with python. I need to add a lot of options (around 185) in the keyboard for the users to select. For e.g. they press a button topic which leads to a `"message please select your topic"` then a new `replyMarkupKeyboard` with these 185 buttons.

Having trouble making a keyboard with so many buttons, I tried enabling the `keyboard_resize=True` but to no avail. After a certain number of buttons the keyboard becomes cluttered and the topics become squished. For e.g. when topics are few: Politics, Sports etc. when topics are more Pl, Sp, etc. The words on these buttons get squished.

I want a slider or dropdown in my keyboard to accommodate these 185 buttons.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ivan Vinogradov , I worked around that problem using an If condition on topics and by creating categories.Like if category=1 then show these 10 topics ...so on and so forth I was able to manage this part.

Answer (score 1):

> I want a slider or dropdown in my keyboard to accommodate these 185 buttons

Unfortunately, there is no slider or dropdown option in Telegram Bot API.

As a workaround I can suggest two options:

1. Implement pagination with buttons like `Next 10 topics` / `Previous 10 topics` to show topics in chunks.
2. Add [inline search](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline), which will allow user to find appropriate topic by typing a substring to search for. `@gif` bot is an excellent example.

Anyway, there is no easy solution for this kind of problem.